# How to write a configuration file to tell the AllenNLP trainer to randomly split dataset into train and dev

Tags: allennlp

The official document of AllenNLP suggests specifying "validation_data_path" in the configuration file, but what if one wants to construct a dataset from a single source and then randomly split it into train and validation datasets with a given ratio?

Does AllenNLP support this? I would greatly appreciate your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AllenNLP does not have this functionality yet, but we are working on some stuff to get there.

In the meantime, here is how I did it for the VQAv2 reader: https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-models/blob/main/allennlp_models/vision/dataset_readers/vqav2.py#L354

This reader supports Python slicing syntax where you, for example, specify a `data_path` as `"my_source_file[:1000]"` to take the first 1000 instances from `my_source_file`. You can also supply multiple paths by setting `data_path: ["file1", "file2[:1000]", "file3[1000-"]]`. You can probably steal the top two blocks in that file (line 354 to 369) and put them into your own dataset reader to achieve the same result.